# How to use subset to get only the first xx observations from the data set?

Tags: r, subset, regression

If I have a data set containing 4137 observations and I want to do a regression of `colga` on `hsperc` and sat using only the first 2070 observations, how do I do that?

I have tried something like:

```
#(loading data)
GPA2 <- read.table("GPA2.raw", header=TRUE, na.strings=".")

#(fitting model)
mfit1 <- lm(formula = colgpa ~ hsperc + sat, 
            data=GPA2, 
            subset=(rownum<2071)  )
```

But the `subset` using `rownum` fails. Any suggestions??

I don't have a variable that counts the number of rows, sholud I have that? In that case, how do I do that?

Comment: subset doesn't input rownum, you just list the rows you want so 1:2070 would be the first 2070 rows

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try this?

`mfit1 <- lm( formula = colgpa ~ hsperc + sat, data=GPA2[1:2071,])`

Answer (score 0):

```
mfit1 <- lm(formula = colgpa ~ hsperc + sat, 
            data=GPA2, 
            subset=1:2070  )
```